# How to add blank space at the bottom of a form in SwiftUI?

Tags: forms, swiftui

I have a modal sheet in SwiftUI for adding a record. The modal sheet uses a form with several TextField elements. Now I'd like to add some space to the end of the form with the same color as the form background (gray).

Adding padding() to the last TextField results in all TextFields having a padding. Then I tried to add a Text("").hidden().padding(.bottom, 500) as the last form element, but the space is then filled with white background color.

Update: Here's the result you get if you put a spacer with padding inside the Form view (background is red for demonstration):

[image]

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true), content: { SheetView() }
        )
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Demo Field", text: .constant("KK"))
            Spacer()
                .padding(.bottom, 500)
                .background(Color(.red))
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is the same as in Apple's Contacts app. If you go to "New Contact" and scroll down to the end of the form, there's quite some space:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a Spacer()

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. Please see my updated description.

Comment: I posted a better solution below with your updated description.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To achieve that, you have to use a `section`

```
struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("")) {
                TextField("Demo Field", text: .constant("KK"))
            }
            Section(header: Text("")) {
                EmptyView()

            }
            .padding(.bottom, 200)
            Section(header: Text("")) {
                TextField("Demo Field", text: .constant("KK"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's it! Can you please edit your source code a bit as the second section should be empty and a padding added. I've used this and it works:                     Section(header: Text("")) {EmptyView()
                    }.padding(.bottom, 200)

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, don't need the second TextField, but that doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you don't need to have the empty header Text and the EmptyView.
So you could also just write:
Section {}

Comment: This works, created a `FormSpacer` view and wrote this empty section under that. Now I can use `FormSpacer()` in my forms.

Comment: `struct FormSpacer: View { var body: some View { Section(header: Text("")) { EmptyView() } } }`

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding a `Spacer()` as such:

```
Spacer()
  .padding(.bottom, 500)
  .background(gray)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working either. If you put the spacer inside the Form view, it's just creating another white row. If you place it outside the Form view, it doesn't scroll anymore with the form.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work well for me, instead I tried a hacky way to add spaces in the footer:

```
  Section(header: Text("Options"),footer: Text("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")) {

    // Your content
            
   }
```